# Specifying a single file from multi-file GIST (wordpress.com)

Tags: shortcode, embed, wordpress.com-hosting

How can one embed a single file from a multi-file Github Gist on a free hosted wordpress.com site? That is, the gist has multiple files in it, for logical association, and I want to use the files individually in separate locations within the post.

I've found and read about the [`[gist]` shortcode](https://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/), as well as the related information I could find. However, I can't find a way to be explicit in the URL of the gist with a question mark, as mentioned in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267385/271330).

I've tried explicitly specifying the `file` and `id` attributes (neither of which work), as well as using the full URL, and any way to get the file parameter appended to the generated URL, without success.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. WordPress.com topics are in general off-topic here. The gist embed isn't supported by core, yet. See [#41206](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41206). So wordpress.com must be using a plugin to support this. Better ask the support on wordpress.com. Best of luck.